# Match the last occurrence of year

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the last occurrence of a persons job end year in Java.

June 1995 – June 2003 (8 years 1 month) **would return 2003**

1989 – June 1995 (6 years) **would return 1995**

The information is always in this format so I figured if I start from the end of the string and look for the first 4 digits but I not sure how to do this
I know \b\d{4}\b matches the first 4 digits but I require the last occurrence of 4 digits.

Comment: Define *doesn't quite work.*. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: You can match all the 4 digit values with `\b\d{4}\b` and get the last one. Just keep assigning the found values to a String var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the lot then grab the second year:

```
[A-Za-z]+\\s\\d{4}\\s–\\s[A-Za-z]+\\s(?<year>\\d{4}).*
```

Then just get the value with `matcher.group("year")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
\bd{4}\b(?!.*\b\d{4}\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZ1oP0/1)

This will match 4 digits in a line when it is not followed by another 4 digits surrounded by word boundaries.

`(?!.*\b\d{4}\b)` is negative lookahead to assert that there is no 4 digit number ahead of current position in a line.

In Java you can use:

```
String re = "\\bd{4}\\b(?!.*\\b\\d{4}\\b)";
```

Comment: I have just run this but this isn't matching my string. Did you use the Pattern and Matcher class ?

Comment: Yes you will need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs. You will need to use `matcher.find()` also to get the match. Can you show your code in question

Comment: Its ok I fixed it, I had missed something out!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the *last occurrence* of a pattern, just prepend it with a greedy `.*`. Then to extract the desired pattern either use `\K`:

[`.*\K\b\d{4}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/kL3pK7/1)

(not supported in Java, unfortunately), or wrap your pattern in a capture group:

[`.*(\b\d{4}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/rY5vP4/1)

and access the group in your code:

```
String input = "June 1995 – June 2003 (8 years 1 month)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\b\\d{4}\\b)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/cMAvFH